# How to boot from a different kernel based on RPI version?

Tags: boot, kernel, bootloader

Background: I successfully compiled kernel versions 5.4.y and 5.6.y from source. It turns out I have some keyboard related problems with v5.6.y on my RPI4, so I used  v5.4.y and it works fine. However, I experience some problems with power governors, I think, on my RPI3 (it always runs at half speed - 600MHz).

In short, 5.4.y works for my RPI4 and 5.6.y works for my RPI3.

Is there a way to use both kernel versions? In other words, can I boot from `kernel7.img` when my SD card is in my RPI3, and boot from `kernel7l.img` when the SD card is inside RPI4?

Clarification: Currently my RPi3 boots from `kernel7l.img` instead of `kernel7.img` - so it is not acting as it should by default!

Comment: Rename the kernel7.img file as 5.4.kernel7.img and add `kernel=5.4.kernel7.img` in '/boot//config.txt'

Comment: What was this supposed to do? Right now, my RPI3 uses `kernel7l.img`, and after doing what you suggested, it still uses the kernel7l.

Comment: That allows you to override the default kernel names. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really need to override kernel names.

Comment: That allows you to have more than one kernel stored in /boot. If you don't want to use that then it's your loss.

Comment: I already have multiple kernel versions in /boot. I am asking how to use kernel7.img when booting from RPI3 and how to use kernel7l.img when booting from RPI4.

Comment: You didn't bother reading the link I gave you. The default is RPi3B boots kernel7, the RPi4 boots kernel7l, so do nothing.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question, however I believe I explained clearly in the comments that my RPI3 now uses kernel7l (that I've built) by default, instead of kernel7. It should be clear that by "doing nothing" my RPI3 still boots from the "wrong" kernel version. No need to accuse me of not reading the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default there is no need to do anything. As documented in [Boot options in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md) for option **kernel** you will find:

> `kernel` is the alternative filename on the boot partition to use when loading the kernel. The default value on the Pi 1, Pi Zero, and Compute Module is `kernel.img`, and on the Pi 2, Pi 3, and Compute Module 3 it is `kernel7.img`. On the Pi4, it is `kernel7l.img`.

If your setup does not follow these defaults for any reason or if you want to use other kernel names you can use [Conditional filters in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md), for example:

```
[pi3]
kernel=kernel7.img
[pi4]
kernel=kernel7l.img
[all]
(other options)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed! Adding a line for pi3 booted from kernel7.img like I wanted it to.